# How to make black and white dotted image in photoshop.?

Tags: photoshop, gimp

I am new to photoshop. I want to make image same link below image. this image was colored before this result.

any one can tell me what should I do, for this.[image: image here]

Comment: This is called halftone/half-toning and if you google these terms you'll find many tutorials.

Comment: I try this but not giving me same resutl like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, the image has been created in several steps, here's brief description and a screenshot of the steps

From the original - colorful or grayscale - image we have to separate the elements which we do not want halftoned - for me it's the white areas *(step 1)* and black borders *(step 2)*. You may do it any way you want - *Wand/magic lasso/Color selection/etc*. Then, to quicker generate the halftone (note on converting to halftones below) we desaturate the image *(step 3)* and finally generate the halftone *(step 4)* via *Filter / Pixelate / Color Halftone* (set all the angles to 0). Later, we simply overlay the border and whites over the halftone and here we are.

[image]

Overlaying white areas may seem useless, yet in case of bigger halftone dot size it allows smoothing out the raster-jagged edges of these areas. It is not so well seen on my image, but in the one presented by you, the effect I mentioned is clearly seen in the case of the contours of ear/eye/hair (etc.).

Note: Keep in mind, that there's another way to create halftones which may be more useful for you:

1. Image / Mode / Grayscale
2. Image / Mode / Bitmap

The way I have described above is quicker, at least for the presentation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The image you reference isn't the result of a single filter. Hairs and outlines have likely been put in after the halftoning as well as eyes and ears.